# Derivative of ${}_1F_1$ hypergeometric function with respect to $z$ raised to the power of $m$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, hypergeometric-function

Hi I am interested in finding the $n$th derivative of this function with respect to $z$. When I try in Mathematica the solution gives rise to two new hypergeometric functions and the solution gets more complex as I keep derivating.

$$ {}_1F_1 (a,b,z^m)$$

Thank so much in advance.

Comment: Use x=z^m and apply the chain rule. Look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_derivatives  and you will see the complexity is inevitable; unless you are very lucky (with 1F1() you aren't).

Comment: So, I cannot avoid to simplify the resulting expression. Which with the rule chain will be of course the sum of two hypergeometric functions.

The second derivative will be something like
something * 1F1 (a+1,b+1,z^m) + something* 1F1(a+2,b+2,z^m)

I was expecting to combine the two 1F1 functions, since I found somewhere this relationship:
c(c+1)1F1 (a,c,z)= c(c+1) 1F1 (a,c+1,z) + a*z 1F1 (a+1,c+2,z))

Comment: Well, since the hypergeometric functions span a workspace, I suppose that you could do something like that.  You are undoubtedly stuck with at least two hypergeometric functions but I would expect that might be sufficient.  Although you would probably need a computer to backtrack higher derivates down to your base and then the coefficients would polynomials in a,b,m; that is p1(a,b,m,d)*1F1_1(...)+p2(a,b,m,d)*1F1_2(...).  I was looking at the Wronskians and it doesn't look too promising unless a,b are integers (negative?).

Comment: No, they are positive and real numbers. So, for higher order derivatives I will keep getting every hypergeometric splitting into two new ones... Thank you!

Comment: Faa di Bruno's formula gives
$$\frac {d^n} {dz^n} \hspace {1.5px} {_1 \hspace {-1.5px} F_1}(a; b; z^m) =
\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac {(a)_k} {(b)_k}
 B_{n, k}(c_1, \ldots, c_{n - k + 1})
 \hspace {1.5px} {_1 \hspace {-1.5px} F_1}(a + k; b + k; z^m), \\
c_i = (m - i + 1)_i \hspace {2px} z^{m - i}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this is what I was looking for!!!